# How group by with value mean seconds in R

Tags: r, date, dplyr, zoo

I have this dataframe:

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   258239 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ Cod               : num  1 1 1 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ MZ                : num  61602 61602 61602 60155 60155 ...
 $ Subc              : chr  "t" "cs" "Ts”
 $ Ct                : chr  "TR" "ES" "ES”
 $ Dif abs           : 'hms' num  07:00:00 NA 04:00:00 23:00:00 ...
  ..- attr(*, "units")= chr "secs"
 $ SocR              : chr  "VILLA DEL SOL" "VILLA DEL SOL" "VILLA DEL SOL" "CLIENTE OCASIONAL" ...
 $ Reg               : chr  "bs" "Bbs" "tyd" "bf" ...
 $ group            : chr  "G24" "G26" "G26" "G22" ...
 $ rps               : chr  "CAST" "DFGT" "REV" "EDY" ...
```

I would like to group the following columns: Reg, Ct, Subc and that the value is the mean of Dif abs (have NA values).

Thanks...

Comment: Did you try `df %>% group_by(Reg, Ct, Subc) %>% summarise(Dif = mean(\`Dif abs\`, na.rm = TRUE))` ?

Comment: Suggested duplicate [R-FAQ on calculating mean by groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/903061)